# How to add custom typescript declarations files to final build using rollup.js?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, rollupjs

I have a project in Typescript which files are built using rollup.js. Inside my project, I have some declarations files defined and I'd like to know if it is possible to add these declarations files to final built declaration file.

**Declaration file:**

```
// src/styled-components.d.ts

import 'styled-components';

declare module 'styled-components' {
    export interface DefaultTheme {
        colors: {
            gray: string;
            primary: string;
        };
    }
}
```

**My current final built declaration file:**

```
// dist/index.d.ts

export { default as DesignSystemProvider, } from './providers/DesignSystemProvider';
export { default as Button } from './components/Button';
export { default as Checkbox } from './components/Checkbox';
```

**Expected final built declaration file:**

```
// dist/index.d.ts

import 'styled-components';

declare module 'styled-components' {
    export interface DefaultTheme {
        colors: {
            gray: string;
            primary: string;
        };
    }
}

export { default as DesignSystemProvider, } from './providers/DesignSystemProvider';
export { default as Button } from './components/Button';
export { default as Checkbox } from './components/Checkbox';
```

#### Reason

When I import this library in another, I'd like to have the typings of styled-components props.

#### Configuration Files

```
// rollup.config.js

import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import nodeResolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import peerDepsExternal from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';
import url from 'rollup-plugin-url';
import { sizeSnapshot } from 'rollup-plugin-size-snapshot';

import pkg from './package.json';

export default {
    input: 'src/index.ts',
    output: [
        {
            file: pkg.module,
            format: 'es',
            exports: 'named',
        },
    ],
    plugins: [
        peerDepsExternal({
            includeDependencies: true,
        }),
        url(),
        nodeResolve({
            // browser: true solves
            // indexof (imported by ../../../node_modules/component-classes/index.js, indexof?commonjs-external)
            browser: true,
            extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx', '.json'],
        }),
        typescript({
            exclude: ['**/*.stories.tsx', '**/*.spec.tsx'],
            rollupCommonJSResolveHack: true,
            clean: true,
        }),
        commonjs({
            include: /\**node_modules\**/,
        }),
        postcss(),
        sizeSnapshot(),
    ],
};
```

```
// tsconfig.json

{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "build",
        "module": "esnext",
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["es6", "dom", "es2016", "es2017"],
        "sourceMap": true,
        "allowJs": false,
        "jsx": "react",
        "declaration": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true
    },
    "include": ["src"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "build", "dist", "example", "rollup.config.js"]
}
```

Comment: could try adding that file as an entry point

Comment: Can you rename `styled-components.d.ts` to `styled-components.ts`?

Comment: @Pace works for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got this working following these steps

1. Rename `src/styled-components.d.ts` file to `styled-components.ts`
2. Add `export {};` at the end of `styled-components.ts` file
3. Add `import './styled-components`;` at the beginning of entry file.